# R - Dynamically Switch Between Variables in a Data Frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has a collection of many zip codes and "city,state" in the US. So for instance it might read (note that the actual data frame has like 25000 observations):

```
zip.codes = c(33603, 33701, 32835)
place.names = c("Tampa, FL", "Saint Petersburg, FL", "Orlando, FL")
df = data.frame(zip.codes, place.names)
```

I am using this as part of a Shiny App. I'd like the user to be able to select a zip code, but to only have it return the place name. So if the user inputs 33603, then the code would return "Tampa, FL".

I've tried researching the Switch function to try to do this, but that seems to only accept hard-coded lists (which is kind of a nonstarter with so many entries in the DF). Is there a way to setup the switch function using variables? Otherwise, does anybody have another idea that might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create vectors `place.names` and `zip.codes` and then try any of the following alternatives:

```
place.names <- as.character(df$place.names)
zip.codes <- df$zip.codes
```

**1) match**

```
place.names[match(33603, zip.codes)]
## [1] Tampa, FL
```

**2) logical condition**

```
place.names[33603 == zip.codes]
## [1] Tampa, FL
```

**3) lookup name**

```
v <- setNames(place.names, zip.codes)
unname(v[as.character(33603)])
## [1] Tampa, FL
```

**4) switch**

```
L <- setNames(as.list(place.names), zip.codes)
do.call("switch", c(as.character(33603), L))
## [1] "Tampa, FL"
```